# Tables : \toprule and \midrule contents overlap and space needed above and below \hline

Tags: tables, multirow, hline

In my table the following problems arise :

1. Toprule contents overlap with midrule contents.
2. I need a little space above and below the horizontal lines used in the middle of the table.

Here's the code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{cuted}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \begin{center}
            \caption{blah blah}
            \label{tab:table1}
            \begin{tabular}{cccccc}\toprule
                \multirow{2}{3em}{Training Size} & \multirow{2}{3em}{Test Size} & Classifier & Feature & \multirow{2}{3em}{Test Accuracy} & \multirow{2}{3em}{Training Time}\\
                \midrule
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & IEMG & 100 & 9.29\\ 
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & MAV & 100 & 8.89\\ 
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & MAV1 & 100 & 8.39\\ 
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & RMS & 100 & 5.32\\
                35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & MAV & 100 & 4.06\\
                35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & MAV1 & 100 & 2.9\\
                35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & RMS & 100 & 6.69\\\hline
                30 & 20 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98.75 & 8.23\\
                30 & 20 & GBLinear & MAV1 & 98.75 & 4.26\\
                30 & 20 & GBLinear & RMS & 98.75 & 8.31\\
                30 & 20 & Stacking SVM & MAV1 & 98.75 & 2.61\\\hline
                25 & 25 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98 & 8.08\\\hline
                20 & 30 & Bagging SVM & RMS & 98.33 & 4.3\\
                20 & 30 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98.33 & 6.13\\                
                 \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Entirely unrelated to the issue itself, but aren't some units missing in the column headers?

Comment: You define a `multirow` and additionally add content in the next row. So you have to add some empty cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you wanted to add a linebreak in column headers such as "Test size". If this assumption is correct, you might be interested in the following code, in which I used `\thead` from the `makecell` package, that you already loaded, instead of the `\multirow` commands.

I also replaced all `\hline` commands with `\midrule` for impreved spacing. In order to avoid excessive vertical white space, I replaced the `center` environment with the `\centering` command and in orde to make sure the table does not exceed the available line width, I replaced `tabular` with `tabular*` and added `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`.

In the following MWE, I additionally added an alternative version of your table with less horizontal lines as well as with `S` type columns from the `siunitx` package in order to align the number sin the last two columns with respect to their decimal marker.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{cuted}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
            \caption{blah blah}
            \label{tab:table1}
            \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccccc}\toprule
                \thead{Training\\ Size} & \thead{Test\\ Size} & \thead{Classifier} &\thead{Feature} & \thead{Test\\ Accuracy} & \thead{Training\\ Time}\\
                \midrule
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & IEMG & 100 & 9.29\\ 
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & MAV & 100 & 8.89\\ 
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & MAV1 & 100 & 8.39\\ 
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & RMS & 100 & 5.32\\
                35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & MAV & 100 & 4.06\\
                35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & MAV1 & 100 & 2.9\\
                35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & RMS & 100 & 6.69\\
                \midrule
                30 & 20 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98.75 & 8.23\\
                30 & 20 & GBLinear & MAV1 & 98.75 & 4.26\\
                30 & 20 & GBLinear & RMS & 98.75 & 8.31\\
                30 & 20 & Stacking SVM & MAV1 & 98.75 & 2.61\\
                \midrule
                25 & 25 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98 & 8.08\\
                \midrule
                20 & 30 & Bagging SVM & RMS & 98.33 & 4.3\\
                20 & 30 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98.33 & 6.13\\                
                 \bottomrule
            \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
    
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
            \caption{blah blah}
            \label{tab:table1}
            \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ccllS[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=1.2]}\toprule
                \thead{Training\\ Size} & \thead{Test\\ Size} & \thead{Classifier} &\thead{Feature} & {\thead{Test\\ Accuracy}} & {\thead{Training\\ Time}}\\
                \midrule
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & IEMG & 100 & 9.29\\ 
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & MAV & 100 & 8.89\\ 
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & MAV1 & 100 & 8.39\\ 
                35 & 15 & GBLinear & RMS & 100 & 5.32\\
                35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & MAV & 100 & 4.06\\
                35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & MAV1 & 100 & 2.9\\
                35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & RMS & 100 & 6.69\\
                \addlinespace
                30 & 20 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98.75 & 8.23\\
                30 & 20 & GBLinear & MAV1 & 98.75 & 4.26\\
                30 & 20 & GBLinear & RMS & 98.75 & 8.31\\
                30 & 20 & Stacking SVM & MAV1 & 98.75 & 2.61\\
                \addlinespace
                25 & 25 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98 & 8.08\\
                \addlinespace
                20 & 30 & Bagging SVM & RMS & 98.33 & 4.3\\
                20 & 30 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98.33 & 6.13\\                
                 \bottomrule
            \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

See the comment for the solution of your problem. I added `&&&&& \\` for free space.

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth=\maxdimen]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        
        \caption{blah blah}
        \label{tab:table1}
        \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
            \toprule
            \makecell[c]{Training \\ Size} & \makecell[c]{Test \\ Size} & \makecell[c]{Classifier} & \makecell[c]{Feature} & \makecell[c]{Test \\ Accuracy} & \makecell[c]{Training \\ Time} \\ \midrule
            35 & 15 & GBLinear & IEMG & 100 & 9.29 \\ 
            35 & 15 & GBLinear & MAV & 100 & 8.89 \\ 
            35 & 15 & GBLinear & MAV1 & 100 & 8.39 \\ 
            35 & 15 & GBLinear & RMS & 100 & 5.32 \\
            35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & MAV & 100 & 4.06 \\
            35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & MAV1 & 100 & 2.9 \\
            35 & 15 & Bagging SVM & RMS & 100 & 6.69 \\ \midrule
            30 & 20 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98.75 & 8.23 \\
            30 & 20 & GBLinear & MAV1 & 98.75 & 4.26 \\
            30 & 20 & GBLinear & RMS & 98.75 & 8.31 \\
            30 & 20 & Stacking SVM & MAV1 & 98.75 & 2.61 \\ \midrule
            25 & 25 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98 & 8.08 \\ \midrule
            20 & 30 & Bagging SVM & RMS & 98.33 & 4.3 \\
            20 & 30 & GBLinear & IEMG & 98.33 & 6.13 \\                
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `\makecell`by default vertically centeres its contents, all `\multirow` commands in your MWE are basically redundant. If you remove them and the additional empty row you added, you end up with the same output you currently get.

Comment: @leandriis You are right. If I use '\makecell' for all objects in the first row, my added empty lines are unnecessary.